# Connect xampp to MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a xampp 1.7.3 instance running and a MongoDB 1.2.4 server on the same machine.

I want to connect them, so I basically have been following [this tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.manual.php) on php.net, it seems to connect but the cursors are always empty. I don't know what am I missing.

Here is the code I am trying. The cursor->valid always says false. thanks

```
<?php
$m = new Mongo(); // connect
try {
  $m->connect();
} catch (MongoConnectionException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
echo "conecta...";
$dbs = $m->listDBs();
if ($dbs == NULL) {
  echo $m->lastError();
  return;
}
foreach($dbs as $db) {
  echo $db;
}

$db = $m->selectDB("CDO");
echo "elige bd...";
$col = $db->selectCollection("rep_consulta");
echo "elige col...";

$rangeQuery = array('id' => array( '$gt' => 100));
$col->insert(array('id' => 456745764, 'nombre' => 'cosa'));
$cursor = $col->find()->limit(10);
echo "buscando...";
var_dump($cursor);
var_dump($cursor->valid());
if ($cursor == NULL) echo 'cursor null';
while($cursor->hasNext()) {
    $item = $cursor->current();
    echo "en while...";
    echo $item["nombre"].'...';
}

?>
```

doing this by command line works perfect

```
use CDO
db.rep_consulta.find()
-- lot of data here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating the results of the query you are not advancing the cursor. Running your code above is causing an infinite loop since the cursor isn't being advanced. Try changing :

```
$item = $cursor->current();
```

to

```
$item = $cursor->getNext();
```

Personally, I prefer this syntax :

```
foreach ($cursor as $item)
{
    var_dump($item);
}
```

**Edit**

The following code is working fine for me. Can you try it out?

```
$m = new Mongo();

$db = $m->CDO;
$col = $db->rep_consulta;

$col->insert(array('id' => 456745764, 'nombre' => 'cosa'));

$cursor = $col->find()->limit(10);

foreach ($cursor as $item)
{
    var_dump($item);
}
```

**Edit++**

By the way, $cursor->valid() will not return true until you advance the cursor to the first item of the result.  Thats why you are getting false.  You have yet to advance the cursor at that point in your code.

Comment: Well, i tryed that before... but the code isn't even getting into the while loop

Comment: Hmmm. In that case I'm not sure whats going on. I've edited my answer with a code snippet thats working fine for me. Can you try running it? If it doesn't work for you, then there must be a difference in our environments.

Comment: @Jhonny what do you mean?  Are you on Windows?  Does var_dump($col->findOne()) work?

Comment: No, Stephen it doesn't work... white page... I think it is a matter of the php_mongo.dll but not sure

Comment: It looks like something faulty in your environment alright, either your driver or your server. Maybe run Mongo in verbose mode and check the output. For this type of problem, you'll probably get more joy over on the Mongo Google group http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/topics

Comment: thanks Stephen... the script worked fine now... It was a matter of php_mongo.dll... This is the page where i downloaded http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ ,  this is the dll url http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_mongo-20100305-5.3-vc6-x86.zip